# How to configure Play an JDBC with Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, playframework

Here is my postgres version `postgresql/9.4.1`

Here is my play version `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")`

Here is my `libraryDependencies`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"

)
```

Changing version to `9.4-1201-jdbc41` gives `sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: postgresql#postgresql;9.4-1201-jdbc41: not found`

Here is my application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
# I tried the following combination
#db.default.url="postgres://user:pass@localhost/20160210_scala_play"

# And

db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/20160210_scala_play"
db.default.user="user"
db.default.password="pass"
```

All resulted in

```
`Cannot connect to database`
```

I verified that

```
psql \list
```

does contain

```
20160210_scala_play
```

with `user=user password=password`

Can someone point me a direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Play 2.4.0 with Postgres and HikariCP yields configuration error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925700/setting-up-play-2-4-0-with-postgres-and-hikaricp-yields-configuration-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, postgresql will listen to port `5432`. So, Unless you sure about the fact that your postgre instance is running on port `80`, change your JDBC url to:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/20160210_scala_play
```

And also, this dependency was resolved for me:

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42"
```

Comment: I got this `(*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: postgresql#postgresql;9.4-1206-jdbc42: not found` using `"9.4-1206-jdbc42"`

Comment: Keep the old driver and try to connect to port `5432`.

Comment: Looks like you miss a "org" at the groupId of the dependency. See more information about this version of driver here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1206-jdbc42

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.default.hikaricp.dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.user=user
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.password=pass
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.databaseName=20160210_scala_play
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.serverName=localhost
```

and use this driver:

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc41"
```